# Superuser account to dashboard in django

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible that:

I will login to admin/ using a superuser account but I will be redirected to my app.

or I will login to my custom login form using my superuser account because I'm creating a system that only have one user. And only an admin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your app will do what you tell it to do. If you need this specific functionality you can read about [customizing the admin here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/). It would need some type of check to see if the user is a superuser such as:

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
    # redirect to send user to the site main domain here
```

Hope this helps!